# Accsesing linux directories every time using git

Tags: linux, bash, git

Say I have a clone of a git repo and I want to use git commands on it through the terminal (I am using the standard Linux terminal). Do I have to do this every time I want to use git and/or access the files?

```
cd home
```

```
cd myusername
```

```
cd myfoldername
```

sorry for the stupid question it's just that it's not very clear on what to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some Git commands require your working directory to be within the project you want to manipulate, but using a graphical Git client instead of the command-line tools shields you from this implementation detail. There is no situation where you can't `cd` directly to a dicectory without first `cd`ing into its parent directory.

Comment: Something is wrong or at least unusual if your terminal starts up with the root directory as its current working directory.